# Is there a way to minimize tabs or groups of tabs in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I am working on a few projects in Netbeans 7.2 and was wondering if it is possible to minimize tabs that I am working on?  For example, I will be working on a project with say 10 tabs opened and I need to switch to another project quickly.  It would be nice to minimize these 10 tabs to come back to after I am done working on the other project.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a little more research, the best I could find was to create **Project Groups**.  This can be found under `File->Project Group`.  There are some settings to automatically save the group when adding new files and to import what you currently have opened into the group.  You can then specify the group name and switch between the groups by again, `File->Project Group` and then navigating to the name of the group.  Hope this helps anyone else!